# Is it possible to add a component on button click where the button also exists within the same component in React ? If yes, how?

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm new to React and tried googling this but could not find answers. Most cases, they had the ADD BUTTON in a different place, so it was easy for adding the child component on button click, but my scenario is a little bit different where the ADD BUTTON too is within the same CHILD COMPONENT which needs to get added upon ADD Button click.

| Header Section of the Component |
| --- |
| Text Box ----- Text Box ----- Text Box ----- Add Button ----- Remove Button |

In the above example you can see, I have a component (lets say Component A) that is rendered within another component (Lets say Component B). I have the button for add which is also within the same Component A. So, when i Click **Add Button** it should add the same component and similarly for Remove option, it should remove the component on click of **Remove Button**. Is this possible ?

So, if i click Add 2 times, it would end up looking like below :

| Header Section of the Component |
| --- |
| Text Box ----- Text Box ----- Text Box ----- Add Button ----- Remove Button |
| Text Box ----- Text Box ----- Text Box ----- Add Button ----- Remove Button |
| Text Box ----- Text Box ----- Text Box ----- Add Button ----- Remove Button |

Please forgive me if my question is lame.
Something like this :

[image: Something like this :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
Create state in parents component

```
Parent.js
const [data, setDate] = useState({});
```

Step 2:
Provide props {data, setData} for your child component

Step 3:
You have function which could change date and change the your dom.

Comment: The parent does not have anything to do here. The child has the ADD button and when the ADD button which is also in the child component, the same child component should get added again at the bottom.

Comment: What i mean you should up state of the button to parent component and provide props to child.
When you click on button, child node add element to state, and after all rerender the component and add new node. If you want, i can share my project with the same functionality.

Comment: oh sure, if you can, it'll be really helpful - i will run it on my end and check this.. sorry I misunderstood you.. still learning React.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-sanne-fq316y?file=/src/components/PostItem.js

Comment: Thank you so much for quickly setting it up and sharing the same with me. The ADD button is in the PARENT unlike my situation where even the ADD is inside the CHILD.. anyway you can change it that way ?

Comment: It does not matter, beacause your functionality placed in parent node and you provide it for child state props and function onClick. For add button the situation is similar. The only difference is that you need to pass a different state and onclick function (for add button).

Comment: oh, okay! Let me try this out and keep you posted.. thank you so much for clarifying!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250093/discussion-between-kay-and-ihelidor).

Comment: I modified your code by forking it. I'm stuck as to how to put the onclick function to add the same component.. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-night-jg9kvg?file=/src/App.js

I added a new component state setting it to blank but don't know where to use that state.. :(

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-moore-cp2go7?file=/src/components/PostItem.js
I hope it useful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this - lot of things for me to digest and understand but this works! I will go through this in detail.. if you dont mind, can i ask you more questions via chat after going through your code ?